# VS2013 Is Not Compatible With VS2015 Project Type (ASP.NET Projects)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using Visual Studio 2013.
But when i open the MVC project code in Github: [https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc](https://github.com/betimer/Mvc)
I found that the solution was built on the new type (project contains: xxx.xproj + xxx.json) (I think they are VS 2015 types)

Is there any way to let my VS 2013 compatible with the new project type?

Comment: This repo is a fork of *THE* next version of ASP.NET, built to run on VS 2015, C#6 and the next runtime. Even if you could open it, you couldn't compile or run it. ASP.NET vNext projects can't open with older Visual Studio versions - the different project structure is one of the main features of ASP.NET vNext. ASP.NET 4.5 projects though have no problem opening in 2013

Comment: I see, thank you, Panagiotis Kanavos. 
In that case i may only access the code through github website.

Comment: You can use Visual Studio 2015 RC. It's free and with a "Go Live" license. The Community edition will remain free even after 2015 is released

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This repo is a fork of next version of ASP.NET MVC. It's  built to run on VS 2015, C#6 and the next runtime. Even if you could open it, you couldn't compile or run it.

Visual Studio 2015 can create both vNext (5) and ASP.NET 4.5/4.6 projects. ASP.NET 5 projects can't open with older Visual Studio versions - the different project structure is one of the main features of ASP.NET vNext.

ASP.NET 4.5 projects though have no problem opening in 2013. ASP.NET 4.6 projects have the same project structure but I haven't tested if they can open in 2013. I would expect tooling differences to make this difficult.